# wlgrid.m error: Undefined function 'ustrcmpi' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab

I want to generate a .grd file using wlgrid.m.
batimetria.xyz is a file containing a matrix (x,y,z).
This is my Matlab code:

```
load('batimetria.xyz');
batimetry = sortrows(batimetria,1);
data = batimetry(138:end,:);
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);
z = data(:,3);
xmin = min(x);
xmax = max(x);
ymin = min(y);
ymax = max(y);
dx = (xmax - xmin)/100;
dy = (ymax - ymin)/100;
X = xmin:dx:xmax;
Y = ymin:dy:ymax;
[XI,YI]= meshgrid(X,Y);
ZI = griddata(x,y,-z,XI,YI);
ZI(isnan(ZI)) = 0;
contourf(XI,YI,ZI,30);
wldep('write', 'bat.dep' , ZI);
wlgrid('write','grid.grd',XI,YI);
```

The error displayed is:
     Undefined function 'ustrcmpi' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in wlgrid>Local_write_grid (line 412)
                j = ustrcmpi(varargin{i},Cmds);

Error in wlgrid (line 82)
        Out=Local_write_grid('newrgf',varargin{:});

Any advice?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

wlgrid.m file is already contained into Delft3D\win32\delft3d_matlab.
I just opened Matlab -> Set path and added the folder "delft3d_matlab".
Now it' s working!